How Do I transfer Weight without Double transformation?
I cannot find anything on google or elsewhere that addresses the issues I'm looking for but what I want to achieve is to project both of the armature characters by moving the bone control and changing the shape by opening the mouth to align each other so it would be easier to transfer.
After I applied the armature to set the pose of my target rig character, I then first selected my source rig which still had a transformation value after I manually moved the bone in the position and selected the following to my target character and when I transferred weight, it gave me double transformation.
Of course I can apply the armature of my  source character to avoid the problem where the transfer process would stay the same but the problem is that if I do this, I essentially create a default position where the mouth stays open instead of closed.
All in all, I want to preserve the shape deformer of the bones value that I changed earlier without having double transformation  after the transfer  so that I can reset back to 0.

Anyone please answer?

It's quite unclear which is exactly the issue you're facing. To my understanding you should simply create a copy of the posed source character, apply the armature modifier, transfer the weights and then delete the copied source mesh. if this doesn't solve, please upload your file or add some images and further details.

@joshsanfelici
Yeah I tried duplicating the source geometry and transferred the weight and deleted afterward without the active armature at present in the modifier of my target character.  The moment I started parenting to the deformer armature or set up in the modifier, it caused some distortion of my deformed.
Here is the link of my demo to help you better understanding of what I'm doing.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Fcn1w7WM1ePq5rgK0hBgljwwOIC8WvD9/view?usp=sharing
Let me know if you still need the file to examine the issues

After transferring weights, create a copy of the Armature you want to use as final rig, posed with the open mouth, go to pose mode, select all relevant bones and Press Ctrl A (Apply pose as rest pose).
Add an armature modifier targeting this new rig, use it to pose the character toward the desired rest pose (mouth closed), maybe using copy Transform constraints targeting the original rig in rest pose and applying them.
Another way of copying the pose is to use a simple addon for copy and paste in world space: https://fin.gumroad.com/l/yndvr
When the character is in the desired pose with mouth closed, apply the armature modifier, and add a new armature modifier targeting the original rig.
If the operation of applying pose as rest pose breaks the rig, you will have to build a new version of the rig maintaining all Deforming bones only: make sure that all names of deforming bones match the corresponding names of the vertex groups which were created during the weight transfer operation.

Thank you. I know re-posing the bones back to the rest pose may be an ideal solution for most however for me, I have way too many rig controls to work with and every time I reposed it back to where it was started, it doesn't look as clean as it was before. OFC I have to make adjustment on the value of my Paint Weight but it's going to be long and tedious to manually move over each one.
I appreciate for sharing the simpler method with this addon which guaranteed the placement of Worldspace however I can only copy one bone each. Copying Multiple Bones and Paste made no change

There's no instruction but I thought the basis of this addon was to select multiple bones with the same names in the Pose mode to other armature. Am I missing something?
Have you tried this addon?

Yes, it works only on one by one basis, but it's the faster method I know (except using a Python script).

I guess the most efficient way to work around this is to create a new main window with different scenes  at pose mode  and copy paste the bone I selected  between the split screen so I don't have to go through the annoying process of switching back and forth between Object and Pose mode with different armature.
Thank you for providing the answer and sharing this addon!

If you select both rigs in obj mode, you can stay in pose mode working on both rigs simultaneously.
